# Haskell Yesod serving large file issue

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm working on a Yesod file server, and I need to be able to serve larger files (in this case, pictures) as well.

I have a static file subsite set up to serve the desired directory. Whenever I try to download those larger files, Yesod responds with a 206 Partial Content response, only sending part of the file, and it eventually times out.

I'm also having this issue when serving files with `sendFile` from `Yesod.Core.Handler`. I thought that `sendFile` was trying to load the whole file into memory which may have accounted for the slow speed, but then I looked at the docs and realized this isn't the case.

EDIT: After playing around with a few things, I managed to solve the problem. I was using the `warp-tls` package to host my `Yesod` App over SSL using the `runTLS` function. It should have occurred to me that these files would have to be read into memory in order to encrypt them. This caused the time outs and failed downloads that I was seeing.

I fixed this by running my `Yesod` app without the `warp-tls` package using instead the `warpDebug` function that `Yesod` provides, and I served it over SSL with an nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: What is the total file size you are trying to download ? That may be a good check to see for other's if it's reproducible.

Comment: Maybe only a few MB. Right now I'm just using it for pictures. Using an existing file server written in Scotty, its send file function doesn't have a problem with the same files.

Comment: Maybe you should show us some code.